# linking of one variable with different make file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am having 3 stage of makefile which is used in project, main.mak, proj.mak, submodule.mak. In main.mak include proj.mak, proj.mak include submodule.mak. i need to create a submodule.mak in a such a way that, files should compile, based on inputs from proj.mak. 
       If some one working on projects, who cannot change submodule.mak, they are allow to play with only proj.mak. My question is, how the value can be set in 
proj.mak which will be an input to submodule.mak to compile(link with other make file). 
for example,

```
ifeq "$(COM_MODE)" "SERIAL" 
    FILES_TO_COMPILE :- serial.c mode.c exemption.c
else
    FILES_TO_COMPILE :- parallel.c mode.c exemption.c
endif
```

where COM_MODE is extern variable to proj.mak and submodule.mak. I think it is not good method to include proj.mak in module.mak. Because proj.mak is already include submodule.mak. Indeed it will be recursive. Any solution will be appreciated

Comment: Why `cmake` tag? As far as I understand the question, you operate with `make`, not with `cmake`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes you are correct, i edited.

Comment: Do you want to know how to set the value in `proj.mak`, or how to use it in `submodule.mak`?

Comment: @Beta I want to know, how to use in submodule.mak. Because i don't want to include proj.mak in submodule.mak. I want to create like extern what we are using in C language